# Detect collision of more than 3 gameObjects at the same time in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I don't know how to solve this puzzle. I will describe a simple scenario below, step by step.

1. I have a small circle sprite and more than three rectangular sprites, each having a different colour eg. Red, Yellow, Blue
2. On each gameObject I attached a box collider and made it trigger on.
3. When a circle is triggered by a single sprite or it passes through any rectangular sprite individually, it will take the colour of that sprite.( It is easy NP we'll do it on TriggerEnter)
4. When a circle is passing through two Rectangular sprite simultaneously it will take another colour like combination of both colours. (Here is where I am stuck, how can I identify the circle and both rectangle are colliding at same point?).

I had used Bounds, but not getting exact collision area. I had used a list of gameobjects, and adding gameobjects on TriggerEnter or TriggerStay and removing it on TriggerExit (changing colour on trigger exit before removing it) but not getting exact solution.

```
    //for simplicity consider there or only circle and colours rectangle. 
    //it will work for only two simultaneous trigger but i need more than that
    List<GameObject> go = new List<GameObject> ();
    public void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
    {
       if(!go.Contains(other.GameObject))
         go.Add(other.gameObject);
    }

    public void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
      // Changing colour according to list 
      if(go.Contains (other.gameObject)
      {
         go.Remove(other.gameObject);
      }
    }
```

Help me out for this simple trick.

Thanks

Comment: I would think your idea with adding the objects to a list on collision and removing when they exit should work fine. What was the problem?

Comment: Please post the code for the list of game objects solution, it should have worked and you likely just made a simple mistake. If you show us the code we can help you find the mistake.

Comment: @ryemoss Yes it should work but what i am looking is somewhat different. I want circle to stay on that colour until it again triggered something else. For two rectangle is working fine but for three it is not.

Answer (score 1):

The original comments on your post are correct, the solution involving adding colliders to a list should work and if it did not for you then there may be an error with your code.

That being said there is another way to detect multiple collisions, this can be done by using the [Physics](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.html) (or for 2D games the [Physics2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.html)) class. In your case you mention having circles and rectangles, so the functions for those specific shapes are [Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll.html) and [Physics2D.OverlapBoxAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapBoxAll.html).

These functions return lists of Colliders which you can then get the data from by accessing their gameObject variable, there are a whole host of other shapes you can use with these functions as well and you can view them all by checking the documentation pages for the physics classes.

[Physics Class Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.html)

[Physics2D Class Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.html)

Answer (score 1):

I will give you my solution for the scenario you described.

Lets imagine we have only 3 types of squares, Red, Blue and Yellow. What I would do is give to each of them value power of 2. For example:

```
int valueRed = 1; //2^0 
int valueBlue = 2; //2^1 
int valueYellow = 4; //2^2
```

Then I will declare 3 counter, one per each colour (all 0 initially):

```
int counterRed = 0;
int counterBlue = 0;
int counterYellow = 0;
```

This counters are necessary, so in case the circle colldes more than once with a
square of a particular type, it will not add the colour twice or even more times(that would spoil everything)

I will declare a variable to set the colour of circle

```
int circleColour;
```

I will tag each rectangle with a different tag, depending on its colour: Red, Blue, Yellow.

Now in the TriggerEnter, which is working for you already, I would write for each color something like this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
        if(other.tag == "Blue"){
            if(counterBlue == 0)
              {  circleColour += valueBlue;}
            counterBlue++;
        }
        //Same for the other 2 colours
    }
```

For the onTriggerExit:

```
void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other) {
        if(other.tag == "Blue"){
            counterBlue--;
            if(counterBlue == 0 )
                circleColour -= valueBlue;
        }
        //Same for the other 2 colours
    }
```

With this you will get a unique value for each combination of colours:

```
Red = 1;
Blue = 2; 
Purple = 3; //Red + Blue
Yellow = 4; 
Orange = 5; //Red + Yellow
Green = 6; // Blue + Yellow
Black = 7; // Red + Blue + Yellow
```

Then you can set programatically the proper color to your circle in the Update using a switch

```
switch(circleColour){
   case 1: //Set color of the circle sprite to red; 
   break;
   case 2: //Set color of the circle sprite to blue; 
   break;
   ...
}
```

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.I didn´t tested myself so maybe there are some typos.

Comment: There is a slight issue with your code, if I hit a blue, then another blue, then leave the first blue, your code will act as if I was not still in the 2nd blue. You currently have no way to detect if you have entered the same color multiple times and if you have left that color the correct number of times.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain You are totally right, I didn't take that into account. Now I edited, instead of flags I will use counters

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre , Thanks for your reply and solution this is great. What i am looking for when circle passes through RED+YELLOW same time it will turn  ORANGE and stay on that colour till another trigger. if it passes through  RED it will turn red until it again trigger another more rectangle. If it triggered RED and then again it triggered Yellow it should turn YELLOW and stay on that colour until another trigger.

Comment: So as i understand it will be only orange if red and yellow trigger exactly at the same time? If so i can tell u it will be really hard that that situation happen. With my solution as soon as one trigger out the color will change, so could be red, then yellow triggerenter and become orange, then red triggerexit and become yellow

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre It will be orange if red and yellow trigger(Eg. red and yellow is in 'X' Shape and circle is passing through the exact centre of 'X" then it will turn orange and stay orange) and it will not change colour of orange again until it collide with another things.

Comment: @Nerendra ohh ok I understand now. I will keep thinking tomorrow for different aproaches that may suit better your requirements

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre hope you hay got solution, I am waiting for you to give me best solution. Thanks for your efforts.